# Client authentication: only talk to trusted clients?

Tags: authentication

As a preamble,I acknowledge that it is fundamentally impossible to authenticate
that a networked client is who they claim to be.   The question is, given that
it's impossible, what should I do anyway?

Suppose I have a http server and only want to provide services to browser X rather
than all the other brands of browsers.  A simple shared secret would prevent any
other clients from being served accidentally. How should I make it more difficult
for deliberate impersonators?

Comment: Sounds like [Web Environment Integrity](https://github.com/RupertBenWiser/Web-Environment-Integrity/blob/main/explainer.md)

Comment: There's really no good reason to require people to use a particular browser, and any attempt to do so is pretty much trivial to forge at the HTTP level.  If you want to serve only known parties, some sort of authentication is preferable to mandating a specific user-agent.

Comment: @bk2204 browser was just an example of a client that everyone understands.  Imagine instead a custom app that plays a game like Fortnight, and you want to shut out bootleg or modded clients.

Comment: That would be akin to DRM / anti-cheat systems... Note that I've asked the mods of [security.se] to see if they want to host the question, as this seems more about system security than cryptography in particular.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with cryptography. I suggest to move it to Security SE.

Comment: @mentallurg I believe a lot of the potential answers would have a lot to do with cryptography - perhaps some clever scheme involving signed binaries or key distribution based on client identity.

Comment: "Having to do a lot with cryptography" doesn't make it on-topic unfortunately. Yes, generally DRM and anti-cheat systems are *using* cryptography, but their construction /  application is more on topic on [security.se] none-the-less. This is not to bother you, it is about finding the right experts for the job.

Comment: @ddyer: See what one of the requirements says: "Programming questions are off-topic even if you are writing or debugging cryptographic code. Unless your question is specifically about how the cryptographic algorithm, protocol or side-channel (mitigation) works, you should look into asking on Stack Overflow instead." Your question is not about programming. I just want to show that *being somehow related to cryptography* does not mean on-topic here.

Comment: @ddyer: I find your question on-topic on Security SE, because it requires a standard approach to security problems: 1) Define clearly what assets are you going to protect; 2) Define what price are you ready to pay; 3) Define threats, attack paths, potential attackers; 4) Estimate the risks. Only after these steps you can proceed to searching for mitigation strategy. Before these steps are performed, it is impossible to tell if the strategy will use cryptography at all.

Comment: Unfortunately the question is not specific enough to be valid on [security.se].